# Why is $\int_{-r}^r t\sqrt{r^2-t^2}dt$ = 0?

Tags: integration

I *know* that $\int_{-r}^r t\sqrt{r^2-t^2}dt$ is an odd function, but how?

Comment: It is $t\sqrt{r^2-t^2}$ which is an odd function. The verification is easy, plug in $-t$ everywhere you see $t$.

Comment: The integrand is an odd function not the integral. Set $t\to -t$ in the integrand to see $f(-t)=-f(t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach this problem in two ways: ($1$) by using $u$-substitution (the harder method, but easier to notice), or ($2$) by noticing the function is odd. Notice that if $$f(t)=t\sqrt{r^2-t^2},$$ then we have $$f(-t)=(-t)\sqrt{r^2-(-t)^2}=-(t\sqrt{r^2-t^2}=-f(t).$$ Thus, we have $$\int_{-r}^rf(t)dt=\int_{-r}^0f(t)dt+\int_0^rf(t)dt=\int_0^rf(-t)dt+\int_0^rf(t)dt=-\int_0^rf(t)dt+\int_0^rf(t)dt=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

(1) Directly:

$$\int\limits_{-r}^rt\sqrt{r^2-t^2}dt=-\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{-2}^2(-2t\,dt)\sqrt{r^2-t^2}dt=$$

$$\left.-\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3}(r^2-t^2)^{3/2}\right|_{-r}^r=-\frac{1}{3}(0-0)=0$$

(2) Indirectly: the integrand function is an odd one so its primitive function is an even one, but evaluating the difference of an even function on the end points of an interval of the form $\,[-r,r]\,$ gives, of course, zero.

(3) By substitution:

$$t=r\sin x\Longrightarrow dt=r\cos xdx$$  so

$$\int\limits_{-r}^rt\sqrt{r^2-t^2}dt=r\int\limits_{-r}^rt\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{t}{r}\right)^2}\,dt=r^3\int\limits_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin x\cos x\,dx=\left.\frac{r^3}{2}\sin^2 x\right|_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

The indefinite integral is:
$$-\frac{1}{3} \left(r^2-t^2\right)^{3/2}$$
Which is an even function of $r$. Therefore, for any symmetrical integration limits the integral will be zero.